# Why jackson can't cast long to long into my spring-batch?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I'm trying to read datas from database into my spring-batch application.

I have one oracle table with a lot of fields and i just want to get a list of id (primary key).

So i have created a simple job with 2 steps (reader and writer).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Job importPurchase(
      JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step findProSellerAccountStep, Step importPurchaseStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("importJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(findProSellerAccountStep)
        // .next(importPurchaseStep)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @JobScope
  public Step findProSellerAccountStep(
      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
      ItemReader<Long> accountItemReader,
      ItemWriter<Long> accountItemWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("findProSellersStep")
        .<Long, Long>chunk(10)
        .reader(accountItemReader)
        .writer(accountItemWriter)
        .build();
  }
}
```

And i have also created an item reader :

```java
@Component
@JobScope
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
public class AccountItemReader extends RepositoryItemReader<Long> {
  public AccountItemReader(AccountEntityRepository accountRepository) {
    // Get all elements
    this.setMethodName("findAllAccount");

    HashMap<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
    sorts.put("userAccountId", Sort.Direction.ASC);

    this.setSort(sorts);
    this.setPageSize(10);
    this.setRepository(accountRepository);
  }
}
```

Finally i have created a repository :

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AccountEntity, Long> {
  @Query(
      value =
          """
                    SELECT userAccountId
                    FROM AccountEntity
                    WHERE myparam = 30 and anotherparam = 20""",
      countQuery =
          """
                    SELECT COUNT(userAccountId)
                    FROM AccountEntity
                    WHERE myparam = 30 and anotherparam = 20""")
  Page<Long> findAllActiveAccount(Pageable page);
}
```

But when i try to execute my program with Intellij IDEA, i have got a big error :

```bash
2022-12-01 14:35:30.655 ERROR [o.s.b.SpringApplication  ] - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.rakuten.merchant_index.MerchantIndexApplication.main(MerchantIndexApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:328)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:239)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobExplorer.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy107.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:265)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: The class with [Ljava.lang.Object; and name of [Ljava.lang.Object; is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["accountIds"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:363)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDelegatingDeserializer.deserialize(StdDelegatingDeserializer.java:175)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:611)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:437)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3674)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with [Ljava.lang.Object; and name of [Ljava.lang.Object; is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer$TrustedTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:357)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand because there is no "HashMap["accountIds"]" into my actual java program.

So why jackson try to create this Map ? Is it an old cache ?

Comment: You seem to have an an object of type `Object[]` in the execution context, do you confirm? If yes, the error means that Jackson is not able to deserialize it because `Object[]` is not a trusted class by default, in which case you would need to add that type to the list of trusted types (similar to `Properties[]`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java#L298).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was only an old code that was stored in the `spring-batch` context and that was reused each time the batch was restarted. I delete my job in database so i wouldn’t have to worry about it.